# How do Vulcans make decisions?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan

Vulcans are logical to a fault. But I have been watching the latest iteration of Star Trek and I keep wondering how Vulcans make decisions given that decisions are based on, at base, a preference.

For example - almost every decision I can think of is the will to perform an action (affect the world) for a (personally) desired outcome. The keyword is outcome. I change the world now so that in the future I get something that I want. So at base of everything people do is this desire.

How do Vulcans, hating emotion as they do, do anything but sit and stare at a wall? Do they have a list of prescribed wants that are declared "logical" or are allowed. As in, "I can perform this action because a perfect Vulcan would want this as it furthers the goals of Vulcans"? Even then this perfect Vulcan, seemingly being emotionless, would desire for nothing either.

Perhaps I do not really understand how Vulcan philosophy works, but it has me very confused. Can someone explain this to me?

EDIT: This is sort of a sub-question/point but I want to bring it up as well. If I remember correctly Vulcans split off from Romulans who are a cousin species that "give in to their emotions and are violent/have undesired traits (from the perspective of Vulcans)". This is seemingly another paradox - Vulcans practice logic because they fear (an emotion) using emotions and becoming like the Romulans who have undesired traits (desire is also an emotion). So to the extent that Vulcans practice logic as a reaction agains Romulan-"ism" they are betraying their own philosophy.  Is this also incorrect, or am I missing something?

Comment: Woops, my bad. Fixed.

Comment: They have impulses and emotions just like any other life form.

Comment: They make the logical decision. Naturally.

Comment: Relevant: [Straw Vulcan](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/StrawVulcan).  **Warning: TVTropes.**  [On Straw Vulcan Rationality](http://lesswrong.com/lw/jly/on_straw_vulcan_rationality/) may also be of interest, though I don't know how well it fits with the new canon.

Comment: It's not logical to wait with a decision until delaying it is worse than making an slightly illogical decision ...

Comment: Some possible hints for an answer, since I don't have time at the moment. Vulcans _say_ they're logical and rational, but the on-screen evidence shows that most of them they have emotions and do their best to suppress them or rationalize them. Surak's teachings arose as a result of the Vulcans' violent history up to that point; most of the Vulcans got on board, because it was better than killing each other off. Romulans were an offshoot of the Vulcans who up and left because they didn't necessarily agree with the Vulcan way.

Comment: They read the script. There is, to my knowledge, no rubric writers follow when determining these things. They just do what their story needs.

Comment: I think the answer is Vulcans aren't truly emotionless; they just suppress them very well, most of the time (see pon farr https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pon_farr ) . There is in fact evidence that the emotional part of the brain is required in order to make decisions, otherwise you will be paralyzed between options that are mostly arbitrary https://www.google.com/amp/bigthink.com/experts-corner/decisions-are-emotional-not-logical-the-neuroscience-behind-decision-making.amp

Comment: @Kai "Suppress" ENT-era, "control and defuse" VOY-era (explained by the Kir'Shara arc in ENT), wishy-washy between those two timeframes.